# Vertical Scrolling SIlverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

How to get srolling on the browser for a silverlight webpage? . I mentioned width = "1800" height= "1800"  for usercontrol  in MainPage.xaml.  ScrollBar doesnt showup and the all the contents are not visible in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the width and height on the XAML only, you need to think about the browser object declaration as well, if you're using de basic project template you've the object declaration with width and height declared as 100%. This will adjust the silverlight object to the screen size (not considering your XAML declaration).

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Some.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

Also if your application needs scrolling support of some sort I would suggest the ScrollViewer control.